# OpenGL shader gamma on solid color

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, fragment-shader

I want to implement gamma correction on my OpenGL 3D renderer, I understand that it's absolutely relevant on texture loaded in sRGB, so I do this:

```
vec4 texColor;
texColor = texture(src_tex_unit0, texCoordVarying);
texColor = vec4(pow(texColor.rgb,vec3(2.2)),1.0);
vec4 colorPreGamma = texColor * (vec4(ambient,1.0) + vec4(diffuse,1.0));
fragColor =  vec4(pow(colorPreGamma.rgb, vec3(1.0/gamma)),1.0);
```

But my question is about solid color, when the surface of the 3D object I want lit is not textured but just colored by a per vertex RGB value. In this case, do I have to transform my color in Linear space, and after the lighting operation, transform back to gamma space like I do for a texture?

Does this apply when my light are colored?

Comment: If you are on a non-ancient HW, HW can do conversions for you (both from reading from a texture, and writing to a framebuffer). It is not just faster, but more correct (texture filtering will be correctly done. Plus, sRGB conversion is a little bit more complex than a pow). About your question: it depends on, what color space your colors are in. If they are in sRGB, then you have to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenGL there isn't a huge distinction between color data and other kinds of data: if you have a `vec3` you can access components as `.xyz` or `.rgb`. It's all just data.

So ask yourself this: "Do I have to gamma correct my vertex positions in the vertex shader?"

Of course not, because your vertex positions are *already* in linear space. So if you are similarly setting your vertex colors in linear space, again no gamma correction is needed.

In other words, do you imagine `vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` as being a gray that is *visually* halfway between black and white? Then you need gamma correction.

Do you imagine it as being *mathematically* halfway between black and white (in terms of measurable light intensity)? Then it's already linear.

Comment: Max, Thanks for your reply I'm starting to understand what you mean ! Indeed, when I want set a color as vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) I mean that I want a gray that is visually halfway between black and white. Does this apply for light too ? If i want a light between red and dark for example, do I have to set the color has vec3(0.5,0.0,0.0) and then linearize this before doing my shading calculation ?

Comment: You don't "have to" do either one. It's your choice, as long you as you stay consistent. Making all of your colors linear will make your shader code simpler but it might be harder to visualize how intense the color/light will look from the numbers. Vice versa if you go for nonlinear colors.

Comment: @Poulp: "*If i want a light between red and dark for example*" There's no such thing. That would presuppose a maximum light intensity (that is, a maximum "red"), which doesn't exist in the real world.

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your help, i'm sorry it's hard to understand for me (and I've read a bunch of article). I don't understand how I can make all of my color linear or all my color non-linear, for me it's just a vec3 when it's 0.0 there's no color (or no light), 0.5 it's between full dark and full color (or between no light and full light), 1.0 it's full color (or full light). If you have some example it may be really great !

Comment: @Poulp check this wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction#Power_law_for_video_display There is only one rule: all of your color should be linear before you use it in the fragment shader. _You_ are in control of where the color comes from (sampled from a texture, loaded directly into a vertex attribute, etc) and thus _you_ control whether the color is gamma-corrected or not.

Comment: @Max do you mind give me a simple example for gamma correction with openGL? I searched too much but I can't find. :((

Comment: The Wikipedia article about sRGB covers the conversion function. It should be easy to translated to GLSL.

Answer (score 1):

> In this case, do I have to transform my color in Linear space, and after the lighting operation, transform back to gamma space like I do for a texture?

That depends: what colorspace are your colors in?

You're not doing this correction because of where they come from; you're doing it because of what the colors actually are. If the value is not linear, then you must linearize it before using it, regardless of where it comes from.

You are ultimately responsible for putting that color there. So you must have to know whether that color is in linear RGB or sRGB colorspace. And if the color is not linear, then you have to linearize it before you can get meaningful numbers from it.

Comment: Nicol, thanks for your reply. Honestly I don't really know if the color i send to the shader are in sRGB or RGB colorspace, for me I just send color coded with three float between 0.0 and 1.0. Can you explain me a bit how to know in what colorspace I'm working ?

Comment: @Poulp: what's the origin of your colors? Do they come from some 3D modeller? Or do you just set them in code?

Comment: @Poulp: And why did you pick that particular color? Where did those color values come from? That's the question.

Comment: Nicol, you're right with this questions. Indeed, these colors comes from a color picking on my screen ... so my color are in the gamma space. I made a little test to check that : texture half of a box with a jpg texture from photoshop full of a 128 gray, and half of the cube colored with a vec3(0.5,0.5,0.5) and the two half of the cube was exactly the same color when rendered.